# Github commit and issue notifier Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, github

I know that there are quite a lot of bash scripts and applications that can trigger a desktop notification for a commit on github, but are there any applications or bash scripts out there that can notify you for a commit **and** for new issues (and comments)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be directly available, but you could adopt a similar approach than the [GitHub-Notifier](https://github.com/sindresorhus/GitHub-Notifier) project, and grepping the content of the [Issues DashBoard](https://github.com/blog/941-issues-dashboard) in order to generate notifications.

[image: Issue dashboard]

(That or calling/polling the [Github V3 API on Issues](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/))

Comment: Came back and noticed that I never accepted your answer, sorry for that. I'm was still in need for this functionality and decided to write my own. It is working, but very buggy. I'll post it when it is actually working.

Comment: @DaniëlVoogsgerd ok, I will look forward testing your implementation of this feature.

Comment: @DaniëlVoogsgerd Have you maintained your project? :)

Comment: I have and it has been working for quite some time. It's an ugly hardcoded mess though. Implementing it in a different intrastructure will cost more time than writing a version of your own in something like python with awesome libraries as requests.